# How to store an rgb image in an array and index it by x,y in C

Tags: c, arrays, image, indexing

The aim is to program a 1D array with a way to index 3 channel values for every x,y location. The data is a 3-channel image.

What is the best way to store this data and what is the indexing scheme? How would I access each rgb for every x,y?

It needs to be in an array since that is the input to the function I am using.

Comment: So you don't know how to use arrays?

Comment: I know how to use arrays. However, I would like to know what the array index would be in terms of x and y for each channel.

Comment: So start with an array format description. Perhaps you might want to add it to the question.

Comment: By using `unsigned char array[height][width][3]` ? Or possibly `[4]` if there is an alpha channel too. Just make sure `width` isn't a bit bigger than actual width because of *stride* - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stride_of_an_array

Comment: Thanks, that would work but I need the data in a 1D array, question has been updated.

Comment: What about rgb values? 8 bit per color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are simply want to code rgb 24 bit colors you could pack them into a uint32_t variable, like

```
   |          32 bits variable             |
    UUUU UUUU RRRR RRRR GGGG GGGG BBBB BBBB
   | unused  |   red   |   green |   blue  |
```

Then you could declare a simple `uint32_t array[x*y]`

Then you must translate it to 2D array where:

```
x = index_of_array/NUM_OF_IMAGECOLS;
y = index_of_array-(x*NUM_OF_IMAGECOLS);
```

To assign color to each uint32_t array element, assuming that each value is read in a 32 bit variable:

```
array[index_of_array] |= ((red<<16) | (green<<8) | blue);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can quickly calculate what the index if the 1D array by applying the following...

```
index = image_width * channel_count * column_offset + row_offset * channel_count
```

Of course that math could be optimized, but it'll get you started.

Given I create an RGB data with

```
 convert -size 3x3 gradient:yellow-blue -depth 8 rgb:- | hexdump
 0000000 ff ff 00 ff ff 00 ff ff 00 80 80 80 80 80 80 80
 0000010 80 80 00 00 ff 00 00 ff 00 00 ff               
 000001b
```

I can print out each pixel's RGB values by index

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    unsigned char blob[0x1b] = {
        0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00,
        0x80, 0x80, 0x80, 0x80, 0x80, 0x80, 0x80, 0x80, 0x80,
        0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff
    };
    size_t x,y,w,h, index;
    for (y=0, h=3; y<h; y++) { // Rows
        for (x=0, w=3; x<w; x++) { // Columns
            // Get pixel at (x,y)
            index = w * 3 * y + x * 3;
            printf("%02zu: #%02x%02x%02x\n",
                   index,
                   blob[index+0],  // Red
                   blob[index+1],  // Green
                   blob[index+2]); // Blue
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Which outputs

```
00: #ffff00
03: #ffff00
06: #ffff00
09: #808080
12: #808080
15: #808080
18: #0000ff
21: #0000ff
24: #0000ff
```

Comment: When I run your code I get a different output, but if I change the type of the array and data from unsigned char to int, it works. Why would that be? Thanks

Comment: In my example, I opted to use quantum depth of 8bit (32bit for a RGBA pixel). If I remove `-depth 8` from my data-generation script, then our behavior/output would match. ( _hint: You haven't shown us the data/code, so I can only guess._ )

Comment: Not sure if you know, or used, this... `convert -size 3x3 gradient:yellow-blue -depth 8 rgb:- | xxd -i`